# .htaccess - writing efficient codes using chain, next for url redirects

Tags: php, .htaccess, friendly-url

Suppose I have URLs as following on a user browsing page (www.date.com):
www.date.com/Location-A/Education-B/Sex-C/Interest-D/

The situation is a user may browse only a number (1 or 2) of all (4) available criterias
www.date.com/Education-B/ or
www.date.com/Sex-C/Interest-E/

Also suppose the order of browsing criteria in the URL matter (i.e. A/B - ok, but B/A is not ok)

I had codes in my `.htaccess` file

RewriteEngine On

## 1 variable case

```
RewriteRule ^/Location-([^/]+)/$ /index.php?Location=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^/Education-([^/]+)/$ /index.php?Education=$1 [L]
```

(...)

## 2 variables case

(...)

## 4 variables case

```
RewriteRule ^/Location-([^/]+)/Education-([^/]+)/Sex-([^/]+)/Interest-([^/]+)/$ /index.php?Location=$1&Education=$2&Sex=$3&Interest=$4 [L]
```

This will get stupidly long if I have 8 variables.

***Is there smarter way of achieving above? Possibly using [C] - chain or [N] - next? (the order of URL variables matter)***

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/$ /index.php?$1=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/$ /index.php?$1=$2&$3=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/$ /index.php?$1=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6 [L]
RewriteRule ^/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/$ /index.php?$1=$2&$3=$4&$5=$6&$7=$8 [L]
...
```

Comment: What I meant was "how to write smarter (& shorter) codes". Your single line code doesn't work when user select less than 4 criterias. - 404 error.

Comment: @user706087 I could not extract this from your question. I edited my answer. I hope this helps you.

Comment: Actually this also doesn't help. Your 4 lines of code will return 404 error if a user browses E only. (since no RewriteRule defined for E case alone) So my question was that this simple RewriteRule lists will increase exponentially as I add more search criteria. For example "If I had 9 search criterias. How can I achieve the above without writing thousands of simple RewriteRule codes? Any nested kind of smarter way?" - Sorry about the original posting if it confused you.

Comment: @user706087 I have edited my answer. Now it will use everything from / to - as key and everything from - to / as value. You can easily extend this to 9 criteria with only 9 lines of code in your htaccess. I hope this is what you are looking for :-)

Comment: @user706087 Any response? Did it help?